# Check mouse click

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouseevent

This code should check the mouse position, and if the mouse clicks show this `X` and `Y` positions in the console, but it is ignoring the click event and printing in the console the cordinates of the mouse without the click.

How do I fix this?

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
       return {
         x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
         y: evt.clientY - rect.top
       };
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
       var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
       canvas.addEventListener("click", check(mousePos.x,mousePos.y));
}, false);
function check(x,y){
    console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case it would be better to avoid nested `eventListeners`.
Also you might store the cursor position as a `canvas.mouse` property:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', getMousePos);
canvas.addEventListener("click", check);

function getMousePos(evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  canvas.mouse = {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function check() {
  console.log(canvas.mouse.x);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ddd
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

> but it is ignoring the click event and printing in console the cordinates of the mouse without the click. How do i fix this?

It's  doing that because of the `mousemove` is firing whenever you move the mouse inside the canvas, and this line :

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", check(mousePos.x,mousePos.y));
```

Is calling the `check()` function that's why it's printing without a click.

as a side note when supplying a call back don't use `()` because that is invoking the function, and whatever it returns will become the callback, instead you supply the name of the function.

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", check);
```

---

Since you want it to print mouse position on click, You don't necessarily need `mousemove`, a simple click event is enough

## DEMO

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log('X:' + e.clientX, 'Y:' + e.clientY);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```